# Why Isn't the Z-Index Attribute Positioning this DIV Properly?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have one `div` I'd like to position over the `div` next to it.

The `divs` are siblings. The `div` I'm wanting to move over top has an `iframe` in it while the first `div` that already has been positioned properly has an `img` in it.

I have positioned the `img div` with the 'relative' attribute and gave it a 'z-index' of -1.

I then set the `iframe div` to 'margin-right' over the the `img div`, but it won't work.

I have tried setting the `iframe div` to be positioned, but even that hasn't worked.

```html
<div class="imagecontainer">
<img class="image" src="images/folder-number.png">
</div>

<div class="video">
<iframe width="300" height="169" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_xxxxxxxx_w" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

```css
.image {
    width: 32vw;
    height: auto;
    z-index: inherit;
}
.imagecontainer {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 12vw;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
.video {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5vw;
}
```

I'm wanting the `iframe div` just to slide over a bit on top of the `img div`, but instead it just won't move over it at all.

Comment: use negative margin-left for the video

Comment: Bless you good sir. I have no idea why that works (guessing because of the negative z-index), but thanks a ton.

Comment: you can remove z-index, it will also work since the iframe come later

Comment: I tried that and the iframe went behind the image so I'll just leave it for now.

Comment: you need to also remove positon:relative too

Answer (score 0):

Using a negative value in the 'margin-left' attribute in place of 'margin-right' in the 'video' class works and properly moves the iframe div.